# chef LWRP remote_file_notification

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I have an LWRP that downloads a file as part of its step, and I want to use that to indicate if the resource has changed

```
action: install do

  # some other stuff here

  remote_file "/some/file" do
    source node[:mycookbook][:source_file]
    mode 00755
    action :create
    notifies :run, 'ruby_block[set_status]', :immediately
  end

  ruby_block 'set_status' do
    block do
      new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
    end
  end
end
```

And in my cookbook my I have:

```
 my_provider do
    # configure
    notifies :run, 'something_else', :immediately
 end
```

It doesn't seem to matter if the remote_file runs or not, `something_else` is not notified, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I've never seen someone try to use a ruby_block inside a provider action, since the action already runs at converge time (there's no need to delay the code with a ruby block). Can you post a log to show us which resources are updated (nor not updated) and when/what order?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to use a ruby block, but it was always returning false. I wonder if that's because it was being evaluated at compile time, not after remote_file actually ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can delay `new_resource.updated_by_last_action` using a ruby_block (you're trying to run it outside the execution of your provider?). Since your provider action is running at converge time already, I wouldn't normally use a ruby block here. I'd do something like:

```
action: install do

  # some other stuff here

  some_file = remote_file "/some/file" do
    source node[:mycookbook][:source_file]
    mode 00755
    action :nothing
    notifies :run, 'ruby_block[set_status]', :immediately
  end
  some_file.run_action(:create)
  new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true) if some_file.updated_by_last_action?

end
```

The other benefit of calling `run_action` on `remote_file` immediately is that you're no longer using the DSL to create and add the `remote_file` resource to the resource collection, and then waiting for chef to converge it at some future time (and then waiting for your ruby_block after that). You're converging the resource you care about right then & there, and checking to see if it was changed (and updating your custom resource accordingly).

Comment: I'll try with the `some_file.run_action(:create)`. I think that was the piece I was missing.